# VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED when trying to register output in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to register a variable with the output to a query of a F5 pool and I'm getting this error:

```
"<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
```

What is that I'm doing wrong?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

```
---
- name: GRAB F5 FACTS
  hosts: f5
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Collect BIG-IP facts
      bigip_device_facts:
        gather_subset: ltm-pools
        provider: "{{ prov }}"
      register: bigip_device_facts

    - name: FACTS OUTPUT
      debug:
        var: "{{ item.members | rejectattr('state', 'match', '^present$') | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
      register: jkout
      with_items: "{{ bigip_device_facts.ltm_pools }}" 
      when: item.full_path  == "/Common/mypool"

    - name: Set a variable
      debug:
        msg: "jkvar={{ jkout }}"
```

Answer (score 12):

You are using the `debug:` module with the option `var:` and this expects a variable, not a jinja2 template.

So either change it to:

```
debug:
  var: item.members
```

or

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ item.members }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like said by @dgw, the problem is with the `var` option of `debug` module.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#parameters

This playbooks works:

```
  - name: test rejectattr
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no

    vars:
      members:
        - { name: "one", state: "present" }
        - { name: "two", state: "absent" }
        - { name: "three", state: "present" }

    tasks:

      - name: FACTS OUTPUT
        debug:
          msg: "{{ members | rejectattr('state', 'match', '^present$') | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I'll investigate it further.
Apart from that, I think I've been able to solve it another way.

```
    - name: FACTS OUTPUT
  set_fact:
    listado: "{{ item.members | rejectattr('state', 'match', '^present$') | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
  with_items: "{{ bigip_device_facts.ltm_pools }}"
  when: item.full_path  == "/Common/mypool"
- debug: msg={{ listado }}
  register: jkout

- name: Set a variable
  debug:
    msg: "jkvar={{ jkout }}"
```

Is that a right way to do it?
Thanks!!